# Spring security - custom keep alive controller

Tags: java, spring, http, session, spring-security

Is it possible to expose a controller with keep alive controller that recieve userId \ SessionID and refreshes the session of the targeted user?

i.e :

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/keepalive", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public void keepalive(@RequestBody String userIdOrSessionId) {

      this.refreshSessionForUser(userIdOrSessionId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the session ID, then you can just send a request using that session ID (set the `JSESSIONID` cookie) and the servlet container will reset the timeout for that session (assuming that's what you mean by "refresh"). I'm not aware of any other standard way of doing it, though you can probably write custom code based on the actual container you're using.

Something like:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(yourKeepAliveUrl).openConnection();
connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=<theSessionId>");
connection.connect();
```

should do it.

The actual keep-alive URL doesn't have to do anything. You just need some way of invoking the request.

Comment: This works, Although it has the smell of "black magic" ;) I wished a more straight forward way existed.